# gradle copy file task not working in build

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle, I want copy the jar file generated by `gradlew build` to another dir.

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    from "build/libs/gs.jar"
    into "D:/bin/gs"
}
```

I add above task to the build.gradle which belong to gs module which will generate gs.jar.

The problem is the command `gradlew build` will not do the copy and this task indeed executed(I add println in myCopyTask). However, the command `gradlew myCopyTask` works.

First I thought maybe the copy task running too early, so I change it to

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
        from "build/libs/gs.jar"
        into "D:/bin/gs"
    }
}
```

This is not working even by `gradlew myCopyTask`. Only first version can work by command `gradlew myCopyTask`, the terminal will show: *1 actionable task: 1 executed*

What is the problem?

Comment: Don't mix up task configuration (that's why you see your println being run) with task execution. To execute the task you must either specify it on the command line or add it as dependency to another task that is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't wired the task into Gradle's [DAG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) so currently it will only executed when you do `gradlew myCopyTask`

You'll probably do something like

```
apply plugin: 'base' // adds build and assemble lifecycle tasks
task myJarTask(type:Jar) {...} 
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn myJarTask
    ... 
} 
assemble.dependsOn myCopyTask
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies